# How to change login screen?

Tags: greeter, display, wallpaper, user

Guys help me change my login screen wallpaper.

I've already tried instructions with replacing the default file and nothing happened. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to change the wallpaper for when your user is selected or place a static wallpaper for all users in the login screen?

Comment: I want it to be the same static wallpaper for all users